# In ZFC set theory, it it possible for a set to exist though being defined by a contradictory property?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question

I've just had a conversation with Chat GPT on the question " is the set of married bachelors a subset of the set of human beings"?  The end of our conversation beared on the crucial point " is the set of married bachelors identical to the empty set?".

The Bot seems to make an ad hoc rhetorical move at the end of the discussion ; claiming that the set of " married bachelors" , being defined by a contradictory property, does not exist ( which, alledgedly  prevents me from saying that it is identical to the empty set, and consequently included in the set of human beings).

***Is there any mathematical reason to say that a set defined in a contradictory manner cannot exist?***

The Bot's final answer :

*

> I apologize if it appeared that I was trying to escape the conclusion.
> I want to be clear that I am not negating the existence of the set of
> "married bachelors" in order to avoid a conclusion. Rather, I am being
> consistent with the principles of set theory and logic. In formal
> mathematical set theory, a set must have well-defined and
> non-contradictory properties in order to exist. The term "married
> bachelors" is contradictory, as we have discussed, because it refers
> to a set of objects that cannot exist by definition. Therefore, the
> set of "married bachelors" does not exist in formal mathematical set
> theory. However, outside of formal mathematical set theory, people may
> use terms like "married bachelors" in a figurative or metaphorical
> sense to refer to situations or concepts that are similarly
> self-contradictory or impossible. In such cases, the term "married
> bachelors" may not refer to a well-defined set."

- 

Comment: Don't waste your time on listening to such bullshit.

Comment: Doubt arose in my head after the machine denied that " the set of all x such that x is not identical to x" is an example of a set defined in a contradictory manner , because " x is not identical to x" is not a formal contradiction.

Comment: Better trust yourself. This robot is deceiveing you with its imprecise words "defined in a contradictory manner" and "formal contradiction".

Comment: Well, at least it is right in saying that "married bachelors" don't exist in formal mathematical set theory, but not for the given reason. It's simply because bachelors are not sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of married bachelors would be empty, since no such person exists. There are occasions where a set can be ill-defined (Russell's Paradox being the textbook example), but here you're just describing the set of all square circles. You might as well be talking about the set of all of Santa's elves, since no such thing as an elf exists, and so the set of all such things is empty.

The difference between talking about the set of all things which can't exist and something like Russell's paradox is a little tough to articulate, but generally speaking, problems like Russell's Paradox tend to crop up when you (try to) talk about the set of all sets with some given property. Generally speaking, if you stick to just defining what is in your set, it's hard to go wrong. You might get something silly (like the set of all married bachelors, which is just a silly way to name the empty set), but you won't break anything.

Finally, you didn't ask, but I feel I must say it anyways: **Please** don't use ChatGPT as a source of information for math. I've seen it fail spectacularly at far simpler questions, and wouldn't trust it as far as I could throw it.

Comment: I perfectly agree with your piece of advice, I was just playing with the machine to test its abilities.

Comment: Wouldn't the crucial difference be axiom schema of separation?

Comment: @Ennar Despite the question's title, I think this question is really more about naïve set theory -by which I mean set theory as the vast majority of all mathematicians use it in their daily lives- than the much more formal and rigorous ZFC which I understand as a formalization of the former. So you might be right. I'm admittedly no expert.

Answer (score 2):

This does not contrafict ZFC axioms since the axiom schema of separation requires that a set of married batchelors exists as a subset of a larger set.

(1)
$(\exists B)(\forall x)(x\in B\iff x\in C \land$ x is a married batchelor$)$

Let  $C=$ any subset of humans, thus we obtain a contradiction.

married batchelor $\implies (\forall x)(x $ is a married batchelor $\implies x$ is unmarried  $\land x$ is married.
which is a contradiction.

Thus in (1) $x\in B$ iff the rhs of the double implication is true which in this case is false.